# How to proof $a = \left\lfloor\frac{Log(N)}{Log(P)}\right\rfloor$ is the maximum exponent of prime P such that $P^a \le N$

Tags: logarithms, divisibility, prime-factorization

I'm trying to solve [Project Euler's Problem #5](https://projecteuler.net/problem=5) which is:

What is the smallest positive number that is evenly divisible by all of the numbers from 1 to N?

I came across a solution [here](https://www.xarg.org/puzzle/project-euler/problem-5/) using prime factorization method. I had difficulty understanding how to calculate the maximum exponent **a** of a prime **P** such that **$P^a \le N$**. I could prove that $P^{\left\lfloor\frac{Log(N)}{Log(P)}\right\rfloor} \le N$, but it doesn't make sure that $a = \left\lfloor\frac{Log(N)}{Log(P)}\right\rfloor$ is the maximum exponent such that $P^a \le N$ and $P^{a + 1} > N$

I need a solid proof/explanation that $a = \left\lfloor\frac{Log(N)}{Log(P)}\right\rfloor$ is in fact, the largest natural number such that $P^a \le N$.

Comment: $a\leq \log_P N <a+1$ is, by definition of floor, the same as $a=\lfloor \log_P N\rfloor$.

Comment: Do you see that $P^a=N$ is the same as $a=(\log N)/(\log P)$?

Comment: @GerryMyerson and #Michal You guys are great! I have understood now. Thank you all for support!

Comment: Let me encourage you to write up what you've learned, and to post it as an answer.

Comment: You could do that today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Encouraged by @Gerry Myerson, I could answer my question in a much more straight forward way.
First, we have a prime **P** and a natural number **N**, the exponent **a'** such that $P^a = N$ is obviously $a' = \log_P N$
Second, we also know that $\log_P N = \frac{\log N}{\log P}$, according to logarithm change of base rule. So, $a' = \frac{\log N}{\log P}$
Since **a'** is a real number, depending whether or not **N** can be evenly divided by **P**. So the largest natural number **a** such that $P^a \le N$, by definition of floor (as mentioned by @Michal Adamaszek), is: $a = \left\lfloor\frac{\log N}{\log P}\right\rfloor$

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
\max \{a\in \mathbb Z:P^a\le N\}
= \max \{a\in \mathbb Z:a\le \log_PN\}
=\max\left\{a\in \mathbb Z: a\le \frac{\log N}{\log P}\right\}
=\left\lfloor \frac{\log N}{\log P}\right\rfloor 
\end{align}
The first equation follows because $\log_p$ is an increasing function, so $P^a\le N$ if and only if $\log_P(P^a)\le \log_P N$. The third equation follows because, by definition, $\max\{a\in \mathbb Z:a\le x\}=\lfloor x\rfloor$.