# formula for highest power of prime smaller than N

Tags: prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

Let $e_p$ be the highest power of prime $p \leq n$. I have often come across this formula $$e_p = \Big\lfloor \frac{\log n}{\log p} \Big\rfloor$$, but I cannot understand how this formula holds. I don't know whether this will be useful, but I only can see that it can be expressed as a sum $e_p = \sum_{p^\alpha \leq n} 1$. How can I derive the formula that $e_p = \Big \lfloor \frac{\log n}{\log p} \Big \rfloor$?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to proof $a = \left\lfloor\frac{Log(N)}{Log(P)}\right\rfloor$ is the maximum exponent of prime P such that $P^a \le N$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3928576/how-to-proof-a-left-lfloor-fraclognlogp-right-rfloor-is-the-maximum) - found using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24e_p%3D%5Clfloor%5Cfrac%7B%5Clog%20n%7D%7B%5Clog%20p%7D%5Crfloor%24%2C%20OR%20content%3Aprime%2C%20OR%20content%3Ahighest%20power&p=1). Also, by definition, we have $p^{e_p}\le n\lt p^{e_p+1}$ so, by taking logs and then dividing by ...

Comment: (cont.) $\log p$, we get $e_p\log p\le\log n\lt(e_p+1)\log p$ leading to $e_p\le\frac{\log{n}}{\log{p}}\lt e_p+1$. Thus, since $e_p$ is an integer, then by one of the basic equivalences of the [floor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions#Equivalences), we get that $e_p=\left\lfloor\frac{\log n}{\log p}\right\rfloor$. Last, but not least, welcome to Math SE.

Comment: this is a well known problem in number theory that has not yet been solved.

Answer (score 0):

Let $n,p\in \mathbb N$ be given with $p$ prime and define $k$ by $p^k\leq n<p^{k+1}$ (and your $e_p$ is this $k$). Then $$\log (p^k)\leq \log n\iff k\leq \frac {\log n}{\log p}\iff k\leq \lfloor \frac {\log n}{\log p}\rfloor $$